# MacOS doesn't see command line developer tools

Tags: xcode, git, macos, command-line

If I run git directly as

```
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git
```

it works fine.
but just git led to error:

```
Dmitrys-iMac:bin dima$ git
xcode-select: note: no developer tools were found at '/Applications/Xcode.app', requesting install. Choose an option in the dialog to download the command line developer tools.
Also Appcode git required developers tools to be installed for git works.
```

I can't install tools because they require 6gb space on disk.
And I already have installed Xcode.
Any ideas, what I should do?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `-beta` part from the `/Applications/Xcode-beta.app` part?

Comment: I created symlink with Xcode.app name  to folder with beta and now all work correctly. I thought there should be something like environment variables in system for such cases.